# How to switch to another application on Windows (using C++, Qt)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I would like to enable my GUI users (GI users?) to switch to a known, friendly application directly, e.g. by keyboard shortcut. Ideally, my application would request the OS / Windows to show application by name or main window title string "XYZ".

The manual path of action would be [ALT+TAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab) to open the Windows *Task Switcher* and then locating and navigating to the desired application icon to finally bring it into the foreground of active program windows. Alternatively, navigation via the [Task Bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_bar#Microsoft_Windows).

AutoHotkey has a function [WinActivate](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) that does what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code works here without problem on Windows 7:

```
#include <windows.h>

[...]

// find window handle using the window title
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, L"Window Title");
if (hWnd) {
    // move to foreground
    ::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the applications really are friendly, i.e. both are under one's control, an easier solution might make use of a communication socket or shared library that allows to have the other application bring up itself.

Which seems to be tricky enough -- delay the call:

```
QTimer::singleShot( 2000,
                    this,
                    SLOT( toForeground() )
                    );
```

to this slot:

```
void MainWindow::toForeground()
{
    qDebug() << SetForegroundWindow( this->winId() );
}
```

This will show the *Task Bar* and highlight the application icon shortly. It does not switch to the application.

Qt's own `activateWindow()` results in a more persistent blinking task bar icon but does not raise the application.

This has been tried before:

- [Bring window to front -> raise(),show(),activateWindow() don’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087887/bring-window-to-front-raise-show-activatewindow-dont-work)
- [Qt Need to bring Qt application to foreground called from win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919928/qt-need-to-bring-qt-application-to-foreground-called-from-win32-application)
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1971

The latter suggests:

```
showNormal();
raise();
activateWindow();
```

but that does not work for me on Windows 7 64 bit with Qt 4.8.1 and MSVC++ 2010.

Here is code that I think is also mentioned in the other questions:

- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1971/#9038

The author writes

> It always brings the window to the front, but the focus is somewhere
>   in the system :-( In some other app…

This I can confirm.

---

Edit: 
Windows' behaviour can (shouldn't!?) be changed globally via Registry:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087923/1619432 points to http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/qwidget_activatewindow_-_behavior_under_windows

Answer (score 0):

Searching for WinActivate led to a [AutoHotkey forum post](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/143057-winactivate-to-c/?p=1007190) which links to WinAPI's [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
BOOL WINAPI SetForegroundWindow(
   _In_  HWND hWnd
);
```

However, this is not a true solution yet as it

- requires a window handle (how to get it by window title?)
- has limited permissions (process ownership trickery neccessary: [here](http://www.asyncop.com/MTnPDirEnum.aspx?treeviewPath=%5Bo%5D%20Open-Source%5CWinModules%5CInfrastructure%5CSystemAPI.cpp) and [here](http://www.shloemi.com/2012/09/solved-setforegroundwindow-win32-api-not-always-works/))

The latter link is quite elaborate, but the author seems to have given up.